# forward input data from textfield to action via button in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

My apologies for the vague title.
I'm having trouble coming up with a way to pass input from a textfield forward to an action I'm calling with the button on that view.

The code below is an ActiveForm I have on my view.

```
<div class="user-view">

<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

<p>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'unique_key') ?>
    <?= Html::a('Test', ['//order/create', 'unique_key' => 'entered key here'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</p>
```

What I want to accomplish is that the user fills the text field with a (randomly generated) key.
Then, when they click the button, their entered key should be passed through to the order/create action. Problem is that I think it is impossible to get the entered key at this stage as I think it isn't saved anywhere yet.

I know this probably is wrong in so many different ways but I'm still trying to learn.

Is there any way I can accomplish what I'am trying to do ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: One way of doing it is to use an ajax call that will process your action under a click handler bound to your anchor element. Are you willing to use JS on your page?

Comment: I have 0 experience with JS but i would be willing to use it.
It is for a project so any security issues won't be a problem.
What would be a way to handle this in JS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need a better form config and a button to submit your form :

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => '//order/create',
    'method' => 'get',
]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'unique_key') ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Test', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```